# What is the point of copy and clean in grunt?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, build-process, grunt-contrib-copy

I've been reading Javascript Application Design - it's talking about using grunt-contrib-clean but it doesn't really express why?

Isn't that why we have git?, I understand why I would keep a seperate working directory, where I can compile from to the root. I just don't understand when I would use clean or copy?

Thanks

Comment: Clean (delete the files from the production or build folder) and copy (copy all the files again to that folders from dev*) that's when you make changes.

Comment: @MiguelLattuada , The only scenario I can think of, would be after a concat to contrib?

Comment: @MiguelLattuada so in your example, I would delete all of the production code, and then copy the development code to the production folder to keep things the same as before?  So your process is kinda like a triangle. You work in between the development code and the production code - but never on one or the or the other?

Comment: Here is a good article that I hope would help you better than me, http://davidtucker.net/articles/automating-with-grunt/

Comment: @MiguelLattuada thank you, I think I was just confusing things.